# Show that an infinity supnorm is equal to the biggest row sum of the matrix

Tags: real-analysis, matrix-norms

I have to prove:
[Imgur link of what i need to prove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2poiz.png)

Where A is a mxn matrix and x is a vector different than zero.

So far i have proved that [Imgur link of what i have proved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95cIE.png)

Im stuck on trying to prove the inequality in the opposite direction, which will then imply equality.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.